# How to fix: image reader not registered error in dcm4che plugin?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am getting the following error when I try to extract images from DICOM file. It works for some files but not all. How to solve this? I am using dcm4che library for the conversion. The jar, dll, so files are added to lib.

```
Image Reader: com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReader not reg
istered. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Image Reader: com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg
.CLibJPEGImageReader not registered
        at org.dcm4che.imageio.codec.ImageReaderFactory.getImageReader(ImageRead
erFactory.java:205)
```

Library version:
dcm4che-core-3.2.1
dcm4che-image-3.2.1
dcm4che-imageio-3.2.1
dcm4che-imageio-rle-3.2.1
dcm4che-tool-dcm2jpg-3.2.1
jai_imageio-1.2-pre-dr-b04

Answer (score 0):

You have to have jai installed into the jre with the correct native components for the os/architecture you are using.

This [doc](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Installation) has instructions for dcm4chee, but the concepts are the same even if you are only using pieces.